# What is more efficient .objects.filter().exists() or get() wrapped on a try

Tags: python, django, testing, django-models

I'm writing tests for a django application and I want to check if an object has been saved to the database. Which is the most efficient/correct way to do it?

```
User.objects.filter(username=testusername).exists()
```

or

```
try:
    User.objects.get(username=testusername)
except User.DoesNotExist:
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

### Speed test: `exists()` vs. `get() + try/except`

Test functions in **test.py**:

```
from testapp.models import User

def exists(x):
    return User.objects.filter(pk=x).exists()

def get(x):
    try:
        User.objects.get(pk=x)
        return True
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return False
```

Using **timeit** in shell:

```
In [1]: from testapp import test
In [2]: %timeit for x in range(100): test.exists(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 88.4 ms per loop
In [3]: %timeit for x in range(100): test.get(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop
In [4]: timeit for x in range(1000): test.exists(x)
1 loops, best of 3: 880 ms per loop
In [5]: timeit for x in range(1000): test.get(x)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.02 s per loop
```

**Conclusion**: `exists()` is **over 10% faster** for checking if an object has been saved in the database.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't need the user, the first one is more efficient, as it doesn't instantiate the object.

Answer (score 3):

I would say `.exists()` is the better way of doing it if you're simply trying to determine if an object matching the filter exists. The reason is because your example for `.get()` only covers 2 of the 3 scenarios. There's also the `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception which is raised when more than 1 object is found matching the filter.

I would use `.get()` for fetching a single instance and use the except clauses to catch the exception workflows.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, in this case though, username is UNIQUE in the Django User model and MultipleObjectsReturned should never be raised if not using regular expressions [I don't know if regexs can be used in get() or only in filter()...]. What of these two would you use:

Comment: user = User.objects.filter(username=testusername)
    if user.exists():
        return user.first()
    else:
        return False

Comment: try:
        return User.objects.get(username=testusername)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return False
    except User.MultipleObjectsReturned:
        return False

Comment: At that point it's personal preference. I would go with the first if readability is more important, but the second if you're more concerned with performance (though the difference will be small).