# Django exists() versus DoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, web

I have some questions about django `exists()` and `DoesNotExist` exception.

Example code:

```
id = 1
# first
if User.objects.get(pk=id).exists():
    # my logic
    pass
# second
try:
    User.objects.get(pk=id)
    # my logic
    pass
except User.DoesNotExist:
    return 0
```

I often use `get()` method. Which practice is better? Which code is better? The first or second?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is more efficient .objects.filter().exists() or get() and a try](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562784/what-is-more-efficient-objects-filter-exists-or-get-and-a-try)

Comment: `get(pk=id).exists()` _doesn't work_. If it doesn't exist, then get() will throw the exception. exists() only works for querysets, get() returns an instance not a queryset.

Comment: oh sorry exists() is queryset method. thanks

Answer (score 56):

> `if User.objects.get(pk=id).exists()`

This won't work, so the question is pretty easy to answer: This way is inferior to the ways which do work :-)

I guess you actually didn't make a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and so missed the error when you posted un-verified code.

---

So instead, I suppose you are asking about the difference between:

- [`QuerySet.exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) when you have a QuerySet (e.g. from a filter operation).

  For example:

```python
  if User.objects.filter(pk=id).exists():
      # ... do the things that need that user to exist
```

- [`Model.objects.get(…)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) and catching the [`Model.DoesNotExist` exception type](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.DoesNotExist) (or, if you want to be more general, the parent type [`ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/exceptions/#django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist)).

  For example:

```python
  try:
      user = User.objects.get(pk=id)
  except User.DoesNotExist:
      # ... handle the case of that user not existing
```

The difference is:

- The `QuerySet.exists` method is on a queryset, meaning you ask it about a query (“are there *any* instances matching this query?”), and you're not yet attempting to retrieve any specific instance.
- The `DoesNotExist` exception for a model is raised when you *actually attempted* to retrieve one instance, and it didn't exist.

Use whichever one correctly expresses your intention.

Comment: `if User.objects.filter(pk=id).exists():`

Answer (score 4):

You can find more info in [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists):
about `exists()`,but `exists()` works only for QuerySet

> Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not. This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal QuerySet query.
>
> exists() is useful for searches relating to both object membership in a QuerySet and to the existence of any objects in a QuerySet, particularly in the context of a large QuerySet.

But `ObjectDoesNotExist` works only with [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.get).

Also you can try another approach:

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=2)
if user:
    # put your logic
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Since we are in Django, we'll try to catch the error with Django functionality instead of the common way(which is using Exceptions with Python).

```
id = 1
def a_query(id):
  qs = User.objects.filter(pk=id)
  if qs.exists():
    return qs.first()
  return None
```

In here, the method exists() helps you catching the error(if there's any).

ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists

Answer (score 1):

in django model,
if you gonna use `model.objects.get()` if it wasn't exist it raise an error. in that case you can use `DoesNotExist` along with `except:`

```
try:
  val = Model.objects.get(pk=val) # if nothing found it will raise an exception
exception:
  you can trace an exception without mentioning anything on top.
(or)
exception ObjectDoesNotExist:
  # it will come here if exception is DoesNotExist
```

Answer (score 1):

For Django version 2.0.6, you can do the following, and it will work:

```
if Model.objects.filter(my_id=objectid).exists():
  myobject = get_object_or_404(Model, my_id=objectid)
  context = {'myobject': myobject}
  return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

You can get more info here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding that you're asking whether to use if statements or try catch on your code. I personally prefer to avoid using try catch, a think it's an ugly syntax, when I do want to raise an exception, I use a python keyword raise, to me, it makes the code cleaner.

Code example:

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=2)
if not user:
   raise ObjectDoesNotExist
```