# Most simple way to check object exist and give responce

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a code snippet which repeats several times in my ViewSets:

```
def accept(self, request, pk):
    if not Company.objects.filter(pk=pk).exists():
        return Response({"message": "Error"},
                        status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

It looks like I'm doing this too complex. Is it a way to make it simpler? Thanks!

Comment: you should return 404 instead of 405

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the ***pythonic way (["Ask forgiveness, not permission"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain))*** to check the object existence bu using `try..except` clause

```
def accept(self, request, pk):
    try:
        Company.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return Response({"message": "Success"})
    except Company.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({"message": "Error"}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

You can find a nice [SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23562784/what-is-more-efficient-objects-filter-exists-or-get-wrapped-on-a-try) which ask samething in `Django perspective`, which says **`exists()`** is faster than `try..except`

So, you could rewrite your code something like,

```
def accept(self, request, pk):
    if Company.objects.filter(pk=pk).exists():
        return Response({"message": "Success"})
    return Response({"message": "Error"}, status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```